# Adding categorical data to an XY plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data

I have plotted the following:

```
t = data.frame(Sample=c('1','1','1','2','2','2'), X=c(12,13,14,12,11,15), Y=c(4,3,5,1,2,3), Category=c('+','+','-','-','+','-'))
```

shown as:

```
  Sample  X Y Category
1      1 12 4        +
2      1 13 3        +
3      1 14 5        -
4      2 12 1        -
5      2 11 2        +
6      2 15 3        -
```

with the following command:

```
ggplot(data=t, aes(x=X, y=Y, group=Sample, color=Sample)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

What is the best way to include the `Category` variable into the plot as well, for each data point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also try this

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=t, aes(x=X, y=Y, group=Sample, color=Sample, shape = Category)) + 
geom_line() + geom_point(size=10)+
scale_shape_manual(values=c("-" = "-", "+" = "+"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could map it to `shape` or `color` in `geom_point()`. for instance

```
ggplot(data=t, aes(x=X, y=Y, group=Sample, color=Sample)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=Category))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or check out `geom_text()`:

```
ggplot(t, aes(X, Y, group = Sample, colour = Sample, label = Category)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point() + geom_text(size = 10, hjust = 1, vjust = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to just add it as a facet:

```
facet_wrap(~ Category)
```

or you can try this:

```
ggplot(data=t, aes(x=X, y=Y)) +
    geom_line(aes(group=Sample, color=Sample)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = Category, size = 2))
```

or like this:

```
ggplot(data=t, aes(x=X, y=Y)) +
    geom_line(aes(group=Sample, color=Sample)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = Category, size = 1.5))
```

Comment: That splits the graph, which I'd like to avoid.